# Position of Keywords in relation to Abstract

Tags: keywords

As can be seen in the attached pdf, the Keywords are not aligned with the abstract. Is it OK and acceptable in papers format? Is there way to align the Keywords list with the Abstract starting and ending positions?
Here is the Latex Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% % % CP ==========================
%\newcommand{\CP}[1]{\ignorespaces}
%\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.e.}}
%\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.g.}}
%\newcommand{\wrt}{\textit{w.r.t.\ }}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
% % % =============================

\usepackage{authblk}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords:}} #1}

\title{AAAAAA VVVVV DDDDDDDD} 
\author[1]{asdasdasd}
\author[2]{dasdasdasg dfsfssdf}




\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Xfasasdasdlifsddfassdafdfass asdfas sdfadfaskj. Fdsdfasjdfkas
fadfsakj. fdasjkfsahfkdfsafsdaasdasasdds. fasdfjkashfksah. fdaskjfashadfskjhfkdjs. fadsasdasdjasdhkj. fasasdasdlifsddfassdafdfass asdfas sdfadfaskj. Fdsdfasjdfkas
fadfsakj. fdasjkfsahfkdfsafsdaasdasasdds. fasdfjkashfksah. fdaskjfashadfskjhfkdjs. fadsasdasdjasdhkj.
\end{abstract}


\keywords{sdadsakasd, asdksdaasdhkjhk, dasdjahasdjkh, dasjsdahkj, dasjsdahkj, dassdahj, dasdasadhkj, dasdhahgj fsdsjk, dasdakjl}


\section{Introduction}
Xfasasdasdlifsddfassdafdfass asdfas sdfadfaskj. Fdsdfasjdfkas
fadfsakj. fdasjkfsahfkdfsafsdaasdasasdds. fasdfjkashfksah. fdaskjfashadfskjhfkdjs. fadsasdasdjasdhkj.
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF result]

Comment: Quick hack, put the `\keywords...` within the `abstract` environment. But please note most jounals prefer to have them not centered.